# Connect PC to an Android phone to send and receive sms

Tags: android, phone

As said in the title, is there a solution for this?
Before my actual Android phone, I had a Nokia and for it there were some applications in  the repo for this aim (series60-remote, xgnokii, wammu).

*** Addition ***

Clearly,I want to connect my phone to a pc running Ubuntu (via usb, bluetooth...) and from here receive and send sms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the best method i found was to use airdroid which works over your wifi and with your browser.

you just install the app and follow the simple instructions.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zYW5kLmFpcmRyb2lkIl0.

you can access all the great things on your phone :-)
you can send and receive sms get notifications for phone calls manage your files etc.
there is a new version which is in beta at the moment which will give more options like connecting over 3g network.
hope this helps :-)

Comment: I've installed airdroid, but I need my phone to be in internet. Also, I don't have a wireless point at home, I have a 3g usb pen to connect to internet with my pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, there is an app called [SMS Control Center](http://smscontrolcenter.com/) that lets you do this. It only offers a windows client but I can confirm you can run it through wine.